# How to loop through all the array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I have an Array of Object to be used to draw a HTML Table:

```
Array(5)
0: Object
   id: 4
   name: Sand Jane
   address: Green Sand Street
   ...
   ...
   ...
1: Object
2: Object
...
...
...
```

I am able to do a single `name` column defined search with

```
const temp = this.temp.filter(function (d) {
            return d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
        });
```

`temp` will contain the filtered data of `this.temp`

Now I just can't figure out how  to loop through all object keys (id,name,address...) so that I can do a global column search in the Table.

**UPDATE**: I have tried this,

```
const temp = [];
        this.temp.forEach(element => {
            for (let key in element) {
                if (element.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    let v = element[key];
                    if (v.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val) {
                        temp.push(element);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

It works but with performance issues.

**RESOLVED: Putting a `break` after `temp.push` fixed this issue.** Thank you all for the guidelines and references.

Comment: check out [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [for in iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: you don't have an array of json obects, you have an array of objects. Once parsed, JSON is no longer JSON - and clearly you are not dealing with JSON, as JSON is a string, and you aren't dealing with strings in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temp.forEach(item=>{
    for(let key in item) {
       //item[key] gives you access to each value
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through for loops or even you can usefor loop inside a for loop. Either way it's self explanatory.

```
var dictionary = {
"employee1":[
    {"id":"0","name":"Google"},
    {"id":"1","name":"eBay"}
],
"employee2": [
    {"id":"2","name":"Yahoo"},
    {"id":"3","name":"Facebook"}
]
};
var employee1 = dictionary.employee1;
var employee2 = dictionary.employee2;

for ( var i in employee1) {
    var id = employee1[i].id;
    var name = employee1[i].name;
    console.log(id);
    console.log(name);
}

for ( var i in employee2) {
    var id = employee2[i].id;
    var name = employee2[i].name;
    console.log(id);
    console.log(name);
}
```